# Files containing vendor as a string not displayed on Github Pages

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I recently released my application to Github Pages, but i started getting 404 responses for files containing the string `vendor`.

Is there a reserved filenames list?

I have `vendor.bundle.js` in my gh-pages branch here https://github.com/emartech/angular2-phonecat/tree/gh-pages .

But the response is 404 https://emartech.github.io/angular2-phonecat/vendor.bundle.js .

It seems consistent between different repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response from Github Support:

> We recently updated to Jekyll v3.3, which ignores vendored files by
>   default. If you're not using Jekyll for your Pages site, you can add a
>   .nojekyll file to the root of your repository to disable Jekyll from
>   building your site. Once you do that, your site should build with your
>   vendored files without any problems.

Comment: This should be fixed soon: https://github.com/github/pages-gem/pull/352